# Understanding code to find the largest prime factor of a number

Tags: java

I found this code on an old youtube video and am having the hardest time understanding the logical sequence for the output. I was hoping any of you can help clarify.

Let's assume I pass a value of 21 to the getLargestPrime method.
In line 17 the conditional statement checks whether 21 % 2 != 0, that's True. So it carries another iteration of the code. But this time m = 3, which 21 % 3 != 0, that's actually False. Why is the code still executing the else statement? This is question #1.

Question #2
How can the if statement inside the else ever execute? When does number become == 1?

I know that this is probably super basic for you guys but for some reason I cannot follow the sequence in the output.

```
public class LargestPrime {

    public static int getLargestPrime(int number){

        if(number < 0){
            return -1;
        }

        int m = 2;
        int ans = 0;
        int numbern;

        if(number == 1){
            System.out.println("This number is not a prime");
        } else{
            while (ans == 0){
                if(number % m !=0){
                    m = m +1;
                    System.out.println(m + " value of m");
                } else {
                    numbern = number;
                    number = number / m;
                    if(number == 1){
                        System.out.println(numbern + " is the largest prime factor of your number");
                        ans++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } return number;

    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
3 value of m
4 value of m
5 value of m
6 value of m
7 value of m
7 is the largest prime factor of your number
1
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code one line at a time in the debugger?  You'll find that it does not behave the way you describe it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I took the time to learn the debugger tool in my IDE and was able to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `21%3!=0` returns `false`. Because of this the jvm executes the code after `else`. In e.g. `21%2!=0`, that is `true`, it executes the code after `if`.
2. It is `1`, if `number` is as `m`.
   This is when your calculation gets to an end because there cannot be any more numbers after your number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan. You are absolutely correct, after stepping through the code as Jim suggested I was able to understand the logic.